# Can't get username in servlet from CAS

Tags: java, servlets, single-sign-on, cas

I have an application on jboss which I want to log in with CAS. In my application I extended Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter and I tried to override onSuccessfulValidation method to do something (I need in my application to know who logged in, so I need to get the username from CAS), but I noticed it's never called, this method. After some google search, I found that CAS uses the AttributePrincipal in the request sent from my servlet, but after it returns from CAS, in the request from doGET method, principal is null. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong? Why am I not able to get the username in my servlet from CAS?
Thank you.

**UPDATE 1:**
So I started debugging everything and I noticed that when it gets into:

```
public final void doFilter(final ServletRequest servletRequest, final ServletResponse servletResponse, final FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
```

the ticket is null (even if I access the page after a previous login (so it should have a ticket)). Even more, I read that CAS should put something in variable userPrincipal, but in this filter, it's null. Session is null. I can't find in any variable the username I introduced inside CAS. Just to be clear, I'm debugging in Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter, where I think I should find my username. Still hoping for some help :)

**UPDATE 2:**
I don't know what to do anymore. If it helps, here's my servlets web.xml:

```
    <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <!--**********Filter 1********** -->


    <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.Saml11AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>casServerLoginUrl</param-name>
            <param-value>https://135.243.36.205:8443/cas/login</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>service</param-name>
            <param-value>http://localhost:8080/casuser</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>


    <!--**************************** -->
    <!--**********Filter 2********** -->


    <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS Validation Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>casServerUrlPrefix</param-name>
            <param-value>https://135.243.36.205:8443/cas</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>service</param-name>
            <param-value>http://localhost:8080/casuser</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>


    <!--**************************** -->
    <!--**********Filter 3********** -->


    <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS HttpServletRequest Wrapper Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.util.HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>


    <!--**************************** -->
    <!--**********Filter 4********** -->


    <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS Assertion Thread Local Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.util.AssertionThreadLocalFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>


    <!--**************************** -->


    <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CAS Validation Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CAS HttpServletRequest Wrapper Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CAS Assertion Thread Local Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Java CAS Client Test Application</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>



    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>cas</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>soo.cas.Index</servlet-class>
        <!--<init-param> <param-name>keystoreFile</param-name> <param-value>lib/security/GiaKeystore.jks</param-value> 
            </init-param> <init-param> <param-name>keystorePassword</param-name> <param-value>The.GIA.Keystore.Password</param-value> 
            </init-param> <init-param> <param-name>privateKeyAlias</param-name> <param-value>giakey</param-value> 
            </init-param> <init-param> <param-name>privateKeyPassword</param-name> <param-value>The.GIA.Private.Key.Password</param-value> 
            </init-param> <init-param> <param-name>cookiePath</param-name> <param-value>/</param-value> 
            </init-param> <init-param> <param-name>cookieDomain</param-name> <param-value></param-value> 
            </init-param> <init-param> <param-name>cookieDurationInSeconds</param-name> 
            <param-value>3600</param-value> </init-param> -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encodeServletRedirect</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>cas</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and this is my Index.java:

```
package soo.cas;
import java.io.*;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import soo.util.*;

public class Index extends HttpServlet{
private Ticket myTicket = new Ticket();

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
        {
    String username = request.getRemoteUser();
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("Test\n");
    out.println(username);
        }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        String username = request.getRemoteUser();
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("Test\n");
        out.println(username);
    }
}
```

Principal is null, ticket is null, request.getRemoteUser() is null...
Please, can someone help me?

Could this be because of some configuration in my CAS server? Or because I'm using CAS protocol for validation?
**Also, could this be because somehow it always goes to doGET method in my servlet and I read that validation filter should call doPOST method...?!**

Comment: Have you tried using Jasig CAS client v3.3 and follow these instructions for installing... https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/Configuring+the+Jasig+CAS+Client+for+Java+in+the+web.xml

Comment: I tried, still null.

Comment: Are you getting redirect to CAS to authenticate, or doe it go straight to your page?

Comment: It redirects me to CAS page, I successfully login and then it gets to my page, but without having a principal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filters are mixing two protocols... SAML 1.1 & CAS 2.0. Authentication filters and Validation filters come in pairs. Get them consistent:

#### CAS Protocol

`org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter` and `org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas10TicketValidationFilter` (or `org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter`)

#### SAML Protocol

> Use if user attributes are needed

`org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.Saml11AuthenticationFilter`
and `org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Saml11TicketValidationFilter`

See the filter details at https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/Configuring+the+Jasig+CAS+Client+for+Java+in+the+web.xml

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I think this is correct, because if I 'get them consistent' I get "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present", so now I probably have a problem with my certificate.